# Access mongodb during meteor startup possible?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

is there a way to access the mongodb during the `Meteor.startup()`

I need to insert/update a document in a collection during the `Meteor.startup()`

I tried:

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 

// await may be missing but when i use await, i get a reserved keyword error
const mongodb = MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)

mongodb.collection('collection').insertOne(objectData)

// Error
// TypeError: mongodb.collection is not a function
// at Meteor.startup (server/migrations.js:1212:23)
```

and

```
const col = Mongo.Collection('collection');

// Error
// TypeError: this._maybeSetUpReplication is not a function
// at Object.Collection [as _CollectionConstructor] (packages/mongo/collection.js:109:8)
```

Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having the error is not because you are accessing mongodb in the `startup` method, it's because the `MongoClient.connect` method is asynchronous, consequently, you can only access your mongodb collections after the `connect` method resolves. You should try something like this instead:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, null, (err, client) => {
  const db = client.db();
  // You can now access your collections
  const collection = db.collection('collection');
  // NOTE: insertOne is also asynchronous
  collection.insertOne(objectData, (err, result) => {
    // Process the reult as you wish
    // You should close the client when done with everything you need it for
    client.close();
  });
})
```

For more explanation on connecting via MongoClient, check [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/tutorials/connect/).